# Defining the Type of List in the subclass

Tags: java

I have an `abstract class Workout` and the classes `WorkoutCircuit` and `WorkoutSNR` that inherit from `Workout`.

Also I have the `abstract class Exercise` and the classes `ExerciseCircuit` and `ExerciseSNR` that inherit form `Exercise`.

The class `Workout` has an `ArrayList<Exercise> exercises`, with the corresponding getter and setter methods. Now I want to be able to call `getExercises()` on an Object of `WorkoutCircuit` and get an `ArrayList<ExerciseCircuit>` back and vice versa for `WorkoutSNR`.

I haven´t figured out how to do this because I can't override the `getExercises()` method in the subclasses and case `ArrayList<Exercise>` into `ArrayList<ExerciseCurcuit>`

Comment: In every subclass of `Workout` you can raise an exception if the type of the object to put inside `exercises` isn't the one you want. And your method stay `ArrayList<Exercise> getExercises()` but every methods changing `exercises` throws a `WorkoutException`.
So you can cast your `List<Exercises>` in `List<ExerciseCircuit>` without problem. However using diamonds operator is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a good case to make `Workout` a generic class in order to allow subclass to define the type of element of the `List` returned by `getExercises()`.
Generic classes allows the [`parametric polymorphism`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism), which is what you are looking for.
You could define `Workout` like :

```
public abstract class Workout<T extends Exercise>{

   private List<T> exercises;
   public List<T> getExercises(){
      return exercices;
   }
   ...
}
```

And the subclasses could be :

```
public class WorkoutCircuit extends Workout<ExerciseCircuit>{
   ...     
}
```

and :

```
public class WorkoutSNR extends Workout<ExerciseSNR>{
   ...     
}
```

Note that the use of a bounded type parameter (`class Workout<T extends Exercise`) is not mandatory. For example `class Workout<T>` would be legal and it would mean that any type is accepted for the subclasses.
But specifying a more precise type provides two advantages :

- it allows to restrict the possible types that the subclass could use.
- it allows the abstract class to manipulate a specific declared type : `Exercice` instead of `Object`.  Which could be helpful if the class provides some processing on the list using specific methods of `Exercice`.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for. Haven't thought about Generics.